# Java Grid fit problems in input

Tags: java

I ran my code... there was an error on line 28. it's the one that says 
hey.remove(whatnumber);
I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I tried using debug, but
I don't get how to use it.
Here is the code.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class ACSL_Grid_Fit {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        run();
        for(int w=1;w<=25;w++) {
            hey.add(w,w);
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> hey = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static int howmany;
    public static int whatnumber;
    public static int choice;
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void run() {
        input();
        countcalc();
    }
    public static void input() {
        {
        sc.useDelimiter(", |\n");
        howmany= sc.nextInt();
        for(int x = 1; x<=howmany;x++) {
            whatnumber = sc.nextInt();
            hey.remove(whatnumber);
        }
        }
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            int i = 0;
            while(i<hey.get(0)) {
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            hey.remove(i);
        case 2:

        case 3:

        }
    }
    public static void countcalc() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you need to add values to list before you try and `run()`

And with this code here, you have to keep in mind there is no index 0

```
    for(int w=1;w<=25;w++) {
        hey.add(w,w);
    }
```

You are starting the index at 1, so 0 is null;

**Edit: I just caught this**

You're trying to `run()` before you even have any values in your list

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       run();
       for(int w=1;w<=25;w++) {
           hey.add(w,w);
       }
   }
```

Just switch them around

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
       for(int w=1;w<=25;w++) {
          hey.add(w,w);
       }
       run();
  }
```

**EDIT: I knew this was a problem to begin with**

```
hey.add(w,w);
```

Your trying to add at index `w` when no index `w` exists. `hey` has a size of 0, until you add to it.

Just do this.

```
for(int w=1;w<=25;w++) {
      hey.add(w);
}
```

When you want to remove the numbers use this

```
hey.remove(whatnumber - 1)
// example, since 20 is at index 19, you want to remove whatnumber - 1
```

Comment: Basically there are 25 numbers that are being printed in grid form. That is why hey.add(w,w); exists. And howmany is how many # that are being inputted after, for example, if howmany was 4, there would be 4 more inputs. Those inputs will erase the numbers in the arraylist.

Comment: What's the error say at line 28? You never answered that question.

Comment: It said: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:445)
 at ACSL_Grid_Fit.input(ACSL_Grid_Fit.java:28)
 at ACSL_Grid_Fit.run(ACSL_Grid_Fit.java:19)
 at ACSL_Grid_Fit.main(ACSL_Grid_Fit.java:8)

Comment: Once you remove a number, the list auto-shrinks by one in size, so the next time you go around in the loop, the size has diminished by one. That's why you're getting the exception. You have to fix your code design, so that doesn't happen.

Comment: See my edit.  All I did was decrease `howmany` for every number I moved from the list.

Comment: it still gives me the same error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:445)
 at ACSL_Grid_Fit.input(ACSL_Grid_Fit.java:28)
 at ACSL_Grid_Fit.run(ACSL_Grid_Fit.java:19)
 at ACSL_Grid_Fit.main(ACSL_Grid_Fit.java:8)

Comment: First let me ask you, do you know what that error means? It will be easier to know what you're looking for if you do.

Comment: I THINK I solved your problem. Simple boo-boo.  See my edit. I really hope this solves your problem. Disregard the code change, I told you earlier. I didn't really see what you were trying to do.  I think my solution now should help your case. Though I still don't know what you're trying to accomplish with your code, This find should get the ball rolling in the right direction.

Comment: I definitely think that you've helped me in this, but I still get this error.     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:612)
 at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:426)
 at ACSL_Grid_Fit.main(ACSL_Grid_Fit.java:10)

Comment: What line is ten. That's what the error is pointing to. Learn to read the stack trace.

Comment: See my edit. I solved the problem to the exception. Please accept this answer if this solved your problem.